# Search for a value in a specific column in the second level of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering

```
$array = array(
    'the-1'=> array('name'=>'lorem','pos'=>array('top'=>'90','left'=>'80'),'zindex'=>2),
    'the-2'=> array('name'=>'ipsum','pos'=>array('top'=>'190','left'=>'180'),'zindex'=>1),
    'the-3'=> array('name'=>'lorem ipsum','pos'=>array('top'=>'20','left'=>'30'),'zindex'=>3)
);
```

How to check `zindex` key exist in above php array.

Comment: "How to check zindex key exist in above php array" - just anywhere/at least once or do you want to check if each element of $array is a) an array and b) has an index/key `zindex`?

Comment: This [mcve] is not complete and therefore isn't a great fit for Stack Overflow.  We don't know what the desired output is.  The ambiguity of "check" allows answers to this question to be divergent in their result data.

Answer (score 1):

You have a method called [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) for that. Of course you need to do some (recursive) looping if you don't know how deep the array with the value is located.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should thing on using [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function in this way

```
<?php
$sweet = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana');
$fruits = array('sweet' => $sweet, 'sour' => 'lemon');

function test_print($item, $key)
{
    echo "$key holds $item\n";
}

array_walk_recursive($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```

this is just a print example taken from php.net, but easily you can adapt it to fit your needs (adding the [array_key_exist](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) in the callback function, for example)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're wanting here, so here are a variety of tests you can run on zindex.  These all use a [foreach](http://php.net/foreach) loop and [array_key_exists](http://php.net/array_key_exists).

**If you want to check each item in the outer array to see if it has a zindex:**

This loops through each element, and simply checks to see if the element has a zindex key of some sort.

```
foreach( $array as $key => $element ) {
    if( array_key_exists('zindex',$element) ) {
        echo "Key '$key' has a zindex of ".$element['zindex']."\n<br>\n";
    } else {
        echo "Fail!! Key '$key' has no zindex!\n<br>\n";
    }
}
```

**If you are just looking for there to be any zindex key at all:**

This loops through until it finds an element that has a zindex.  If a zindex is found, the function returns true, otherwise it returns false.

```
function find_zindex( $array ) {
    foreach( $array as $key => $element ) {
        if( array_key_exists('zindex',$element) ) {
            echo "Key '$key' has a zindex of ".$element['zindex']."\n<br>\n";
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if( find_zindex( $array ) ) {
    echo "A zindex was found\n<br>\n";
} else {
    echo "Fail: no zindex was found\n<br>\n";
}
```

**If you're looking for a particular zindex value in your array:**

This loops through, looking for a particular zindex that has a particular value.  If it is found, then the key for the outside array is returned.  Otherwise null is returned.

```
function find_zindex( $array, $search_key ) {
    foreach( $array as $key => $element ) {
        if( array_key_exists('zindex',$element) && $element['zindex']==$search_key ) {
            echo "Key '$key' has a zindex of ".$element['zindex']."\n<br>\n";
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

$key = find_zindex( $array, 3 );
if( $key ) {
    echo "The zindex was found at '$key'\n<br>\n";
} else {
    echo "Fail: the zindex was not found\n<br>\n";
}

$key = find_zindex( $array, 4 );
if( $key ) {
    echo "The zindex was found at '$key'\n<br>\n";
} else {
    echo "Fail: the zindex was not found\n<br>\n";
}
```

**If you want an array of every key that has a particular zindex:**

This loops through, building an array that contains every element that matches the supplied zindex search value.  When done, it returns the new array of elements.  If nothing is found, it returns an empty array that will test as false.

```
function find_zindex( $array, $search_key ) {
    $result = array();
    foreach( $array as $key => $element ) {
        if( array_key_exists('zindex',$element) && $element['zindex']==$search_key ) {
            echo "Key '$key' has a zindex of ".$element['zindex']."\n<br>\n";
            $result[] = $key;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$key = find_zindex( $array, 3 );
if( $key ) {
    echo 'The zindex was found at:';
    print_r( $key );
    echo "\n<br>\n";
} else {
    echo "Fail: the zindex was not found\n<br>\n";
}

$key = find_zindex( $array, 4 );
if( $key ) {
    echo 'The zindex was found at:';
    print_r( $key );
    echo "\n<br>\n";
} else {
    echo "Fail: the zindex was not found\n<br>\n";
}
```

**If you are often trying to find data by the zindex, you will want to redesign your array:**

This creates a second array that just has references to the elements in the first array.  If you run this, you can see that the data is shared because the one assignment will set 'name' to 'new_name' in both arrays.  Notice that each element of the outer array now has both an index and a zindex.

This assumes every element in $array has a zindex and the value of the zindex is unique.  If some elements don't have a zindex or have duplicate zindexes, then you will need to modify this some.

```
$array = array(
    'the-1'=> array('name'=>'lorem','pos'=>array('top'=>'90','left'=>'80'),'index'=>'the-1','zindex'=>2),
    'the-2'=> array('name'=>'ipsum','pos'=>array('top'=>'190','left'=>'180'),'index'=>'the-2','zindex'=>1),
    'the-3'=> array('name'=>'lorem ipsum','pos'=>array('top'=>'20','left'=>'30'),'index'=>'the-3','zindex'=>3)
);

$zarray = array();
foreach( $array as &$value ) {
    $zarray[$value['zindex']] =& $value;
}
// optional: order the entries in zarray by their key
ksort($zarray)

print_r($array);
echo "\n<br>\n";
print_r($zarray);
echo "\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n";

$array['the-1']['name']='new_name';
print_r($array);
echo "\n<br>\n";
print_r($zarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
function find_value_by_key($key,$array) {
        $data = array('key'=>$key);
        array_walk_recursive($array,function($v,$k) use (&$data) {
            if (isset($data['ret']))
                return;
            if ($k==$data['key'])
                $data['ret'] = $v;
        },$data);
        return $data['ret']?:false;
}
```

In this case it returns the first value it finds (in your case it would return `2` when searching for `"zindex"`), if you need all the value returned in an array you can use this function:

```
function find_value_by_key($key,$array) {
    $data = array('key'=>$key,'ret'=>array());
    array_walk_recursive($array,function($v,$k) use (&$data) {
        if ($k==$data['key'])
            $data['ret'][] = $v;
    },$data);
    return $data['ret'];
}
```

This would return `[2,1,3]`

Comment: The data set in this question does not require a recursive function.  In fact, a recursive approach will needlessly search in the deepest level of the multidimensional array.  As commented on [this duplicated answer by the same answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75920042/2943403), these snippets are [provably unreliable](https://3v4l.org/ZsZkj).