# PHP get array value from json

Tags: php, arrays, json

Using PHP,  how would I access the inner array values,  specific to this example the values specific to each game array,  from a json feed similar to this:

```
Array
(
[startIndex] => 3
[refreshInterval] => 60
[games] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2013020004
                [gs] => 5
                [ts] => WEDNESDAY 10/2
                [tsc] => final
                [bs] => FINAL
                [bsc] => final
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2013020005
                [gs] => 5
                [ts] => WEDNESDAY 10/2
                [tsc] => final
                [bs] => FINAL
                [bsc] =>
            )
```

I have tried nesting a foreach loop inside a foreach loop similar to this:

```
foreach ($json as $key => $jsons) {
foreach ($jsons as $my => $value) {
    echo $value; 
}
}
```

Comment: what does the output of your json call look like?

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON

Comment: If the data is json, you will want to [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it before you access it like an array in php.

Comment: Can you give us a concrete example of a result you want. Should it be recursive?

Comment: this is not json, perhaps ir's a javascript array

Comment: my apologies for not being clear.  i am using file_get_contents() to successfully retrieve a json feed.  removing some characters from the json returned using str_replace().   then using json_decode().   what was pasted above is the array output when i did a print_r($json).   my question was on how to identify the nested array values.   Daniel's answer is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is an array you are looking at then you can reach the values

```
foreach($json["games"] as $game) {
   foreach ($game as $key => $value) {
      echo $value; 
   }
}
```

This should give you the values within each array in the games section.

**EDIT: to answer additional question in comment**

To get the specific values of the game like the `id`, the second foreach loop will not be needed. Instead do the following:

```
foreach($json["games"] as $game) {
   echo $game['id'];
}
```

Comment: can i use like this? ' $games[id] ' to get the list of id?

Comment: @MinSoe -- I added a little more information that you will find helpful. You will get specifically the `id` of the game. You can do that for each individual `key`.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to get the list of id without looping. Can we do something like this ' $games = $json["games"]; $idlist = $games[id] ' instead of ' foreach($json["games"] as $game) { $idlist[] = $game['id'] } '

Comment: No. You will need to loop. To get an independent id, you can use @immulatin's example `$json['games'][0]['id']`. But to get all of them, you will need to loop.

Answer (score 1):

You just access it as an associative array.

```
$json['games'][0]['id'] // This is 2013020004
$json['games'][1]['id'] // This is 2013020005
```

You can loop through the games like so:

```
foreach($json['games'] as $game){
   print_r($game);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access this,

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2013020004
            [gs] => 5
            [ts] => WEDNESDAY 10/2
            [tsc] => final
            [bs] => FINAL
            [bsc] => final
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2013020005
            [gs] => 5
            [ts] => WEDNESDAY 10/2
            [tsc] => final
            [bs] => FINAL
            [bsc] =>
        )
```

..then you are doing it right. The only problem is you are trying to echo an array. Trying using `print_r($value)`. If you want a specific value, like the id. You can `echo $value['id'];`

Comment: and, by the way, your data in the question does not look like JSON. Looks more like a regular PHP array

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use one of the [many example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975585/search-for-a-key-in-an-array-recursivly) of recursive array_key_search. This way you could simply do :

```
$firstGame = array_search_key(0, $array);
$firstGameId = $firstGame["id"];
```