# array search multidimensional in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create a function that for a random array will search for a given key and will return all values for that key in an array. Here is what I have written so far...

```
$testArray = array (
    'subArray1' => array(
        'key1' => "Sub array 1 value 1",
        'key2' => "Sub array 1 value 2",
        'key3' => array(
            'subkey1' => array(
                'subsubkey' => 'sub sub sub value',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'subArray2' => array(
        'key1' => "Sub array 2 value 1",
        'key2' => "Sub array 2 value 2",
        'key3' => array(
            'subkey1' => array(
                'subsubkey' => 'sub sub sub value 2',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);




function recursiveSearch($testArray,$key,$results)
{
   //    var_dump($testArray);
    if(is_array($testArray)){
        foreach($testArray as $k => $v){
           if($k == $key){
                return $v;
           }
            else if(is_array($v)){
                array_push($results, recursiveSearch($v,$key,$results));
           }
       }
   } 
    else{
       return ;
   }
   return $results;
}

$empt = array();

$output = recursiveSearch($testArray,'subsubkey',$empt);


var_dump($output);
```

This the output I get at the moment... I want to get a simple array with the values in it.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "sub sub sub value"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(17) "sub sub sub value"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(17) "sub sub sub value"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      string(19) "sub sub sub value 2"
    }
  }
}
```

I am not really sure why the result array is like this ...

The format for the result array that I want is :

`['sub sub sub value','sub sub sub value 2']`

Comment: I see an "I want" but no question. You already have code, what have you tried to change it, where do you think the improvement needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An improved version of [xPheRe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3975706/1992780)

```
/**
 * Recursive find in the given $array and $needle.
 * @param $array The input array.
 * @param $needle The needle to find.
 * @return Returns all the values find by the given key.
 */
function recursiveFind(array $array, $needle)
{
    $iterator  = new RecursiveArrayIterator($array);
    $recursive = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator,
                         RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $results = array();
    foreach ($recursive as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === $needle) {
            array_push($results, $value);
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

**Usage**

```
$output = recursiveFind($testArray, 'subsubkey');
var_dump($output);
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "sub sub sub value"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "sub sub sub value 2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The updated function of my version is as follows:

```
function recursiveSearch($testArray,$key){
    $empt = array();
    function recurSearch($testArray,$key,$results)
    {
        if(is_array($testArray)){
            foreach($testArray as $k => $v){
                if($k === $key){
                    array_push($results,$v);
                }
                else if(is_array($v)){
                    $temp = array();
                    $tempres =  recurSearch($v,$key,$temp);
                    $results = array_merge($results,$tempres);
                }
            }
        } 
        return $results;
    }
    $res = recurSearch($testArray,$key,$empt);
    return $res;
}
```

seems to work : )