# PHP Looping multi dim array

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [stat] => ok
    [offset] => 0
    [limit] => 50
    [total] => 1
    [monitors] => Array
        (
            [monitor] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 
                            [friendlyname] => 
                            [url] => 
                            [type] => 3
                            [subtype] => 
                            [keywordtype] => 
                            [keywordvalue] => 
                            [httpusername] => 
                            [httppassword] => 
                            [port] => 
                            [interval] => 300
                            [status] => 2
                            [alltimeuptimeratio] => 100
                            [log] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [type] => 2
                                            [datetime] => 11/24/2016 04:01:32
                                        )

                            [responsetime] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [datetime] => 12/09/2016 19:34:02
                                            [value] => 109
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [datetime] => 12/09/2016 19:29:02
                                            [value] => 110
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [datetime] => 12/09/2016 19:24:02
                                            [value] => 110
                                        )
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I need to get the value of datetime, and value from the responsetime array. I tried the following but it seems to not return anything.

```
foreach($multidim as $value) {
    foreach($value as $key => $val) {
        if($key == "responsetime") {
            echo $val[3];
        }
    }
}
```

Where $multidim is the large multi-dim array listed above. Any help is appreciated as I am not sure where to go from here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Datetime inside log or response time ?

Comment: You're only looking as far as `$multidim["monitors"]["monitor"]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multi dimensional array search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661530/php-multi-dimensional-array-search)

Comment: @miken32 Doesn't look like the same question, they appear to be trying to search for an individual value within a multi dimensional array. While I was trying to return the entire listing with it's values.

Comment: the linked duplicate target is **not** a good duplicate, as in effect, the answers there cover searching a one dimensional array, but your problem is not so far @Sam. If you know that the structure will be like that, you can iterate over the monitors directly instead of the root key. then responsetime will be an existing key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search for a key in an array, recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975585/search-for-a-key-in-an-array-recursively)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to access all the response times you should do sth like this

```
foreach($multidim['monitors']['monitor'][0]['responsetime'] as $key => $value) {
    //here $key will be 0,1,2,3...
    //$value['datetime'] will be 11/24/2016 04:01:32...
    //$value['value'] will be 109,110,...
}
```

that is if you just want to access all the response times of the first monitor. if you want to access all the monitors and their response times you would need 2 loops for example

```
foreach($multidim['monitors']['monitor'] as $monitorId => $monitorData) {
    foreach($monitorData['responsetime'] as $key => $value) {
        //here you can access all the variables e.g
        //$monitorId will be 0,1,2,3...
        //$key will be 0,1,2,3...
        //$value['datetime'] will be 11/24/2016 04:01:32...
        //$value['value'] will be 109,110,...
    }
}
```

I hope that sends you in the right direction :)

Comment: Thank you, your second example is perfect and exactly what I was looking for.