# Searching Value in Complex PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, search

I have gone through many posts on finding Value from Complex Array, but all of those only fetch up to second level. Can someone please provide me with code to recursively find the value for example state in address_line_2 whether exists or not?

I have the following JSON

```
{
  "company": {
    "id": "123456",
    "name": "Test Company LLC.",
    "FEIN": "22-2222222",
    "address": {
      "address_line_1": {
        "street": "1 Street St, Suite 12",
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "postalCode": "123456"
      },
      "address_line_2": {
        "state": "CA",
        "country": "USA"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-800-XXX-XXXX",
    "fax": "1-800-XXX-XXXX",
    "email": "admin@abc.com",
    "URL": "www.abc.com"
  },
  "producer": {
    "id": "LLXXXX",
    "name": "Test Name",
    "phone": "555-555-5555",
    "mobile": "555-555-5555",
    "fax": "555-555-5555",
    "email": "test@abc.com",
    "producerSubCode": "111",
    "NIPRId": "123456",
    "stateProducerId": "12344"
  }
}
```

~Harshit

Comment: Can you edit your question and mention a sample input and output and what have you tried?

Comment: @vivek_23 Sample input can be any key or value in the array if I understand it correct. So just pick one.

Comment: @Andreas So, the sample input happens to be a `key` instead of `value`, I return as is?

Comment: I guess you should output both key and value. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search for a key in an array, recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975585/search-for-a-key-in-an-array-recursively)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$json_string = '{"company":{"id":"123456","name":"Test Company LLC.","FEIN":"22-2222222","address":{"address_line_1":{"street":"1 Street St, Suite 12","city":"San Francisco","postalCode":"123456"},"address_line_2":{"state":"CA","country":"USA"}},"phone":"1-800-XXX-XXXX","fax":"1-800-XXX-XXXX","email":"admin@abc.com","URL":"www.abc.com"},"producer":{"id":"LLXXXX","name":"Test Name","phone":"555-555-5555","mobile":"555-555-5555","fax":"555-555-5555","email":"test@abc.com","producerSubCode":"111","NIPRId":"123456","stateProducerId":"12344"}}';

$json_array = json_decode($json_string,true);

function getData($json_array,$search_value){
    foreach($json_array as $each_key => $each_value){
        if($each_key === $search_value) return true;
        if(is_array($each_value)){
            $return_value = getData($each_value,$search_value);
            if($return_value !== false) return $return_value === true ? $return_value : $each_key."=>".$return_value;
        }else if($each_value === $search_value){
            return $each_key;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(getData($json_array,'San Francisco'));
var_dump(getData($json_array,'producerSubCode'));
var_dump(getData($json_array,'abc123'));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
string(38) "company=>address=>address_line_1=>city"
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

**ASSUMPTIONS**

Every key and value is unique in the array.

**FUNCTION DEFINITION**

The function `getData()` searches for a given string in the array.

- If the string happens to be a `key`, it returns a boolean `true`
- If the string happens to be a `value` in the array, it returns a `key`.
- If string doesn't happen to be neither `key` nor `value`, it returns boolean `false`.

Comment: Is there any way that we can get the absolute address of the vlue that we have go. i.e. at place of "city" the output is "company=>address=>address_line_1=>city" ??

Comment: Yes, there is. Do you want `"company=>address=>address_line_1=>city"` to be a string or in any other form?

Comment: to be a string only

Comment: Thanks @vivek_23 that helped. You made my day.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-column.php) to get value of an given key

$array = json_decode($json,true);

$names = array_column($array,'name');

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making it an array. What about parsing it as the string with regex?

```
$find = "San Francisco";
$re = '/(' . $find . ')\":\s\"(.*?)\"|\"(\w+)\":\s\"(' . $find . ')/m';
$str = '{ "company": { "id": "123456", "name": "Test Company LLC.", "FEIN": "22-2222222", "address": { "address_line_1": { "street": "1 Street St, Suite 12", "city": "San Francisco", "postalCode": "123456" }, "address_line_2": { "state": "CA", "country": "USA" } }, "phone": "1-800-XXX-XXXX", "fax": "1-800-XXX-XXXX", "email": "admin@abc.com", "URL": "www.abc.com" }, "producer": { "id": "LLXXXX", "name": "Test Name", "phone": "555-555-5555", "mobile": "555-555-5555", "fax": "555-555-5555", "email": "test@abc.com", "producerSubCode": "111", "NIPRId": "123456", "stateProducerId": "12344" } }';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

$result["key-match"] = array_slice(array_column($matches, 0),1,2);
$result["value-match"] = array_slice(array_column($matches, 0),3,2);
var_dump($result);
```

`$find` can be either a key or a value.
The result array will hold two subarrays with either if it's a key match or a value match.

https://3v4l.org/05dm3