# Get value of key in nth level multidimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a array with n depth. 
i have tried this but its not working for me.

```
array_walk_recursive($old_value, function($v, $k, $u) use (&$values){
            if($k == "tour_id") {
               $values[] = $v;
            }
        },  $values );
```

here is my array:

```
array(
 "ID" => 1,
 "settings" => array("key" => 1,"scrum" => array("last_key" =>1, "past_key" => 12) )
)
```

how to get past_key value efficiently.

Comment: It works - https://3v4l.org/lTAlG

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search for a key in an array, recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975585/search-for-a-key-in-an-array-recursively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, but looking for the wrong key.  Also the third argument passed to array_walk_recursive is passed as the third parameter to the callback (not needed for your needs, but I've added example use below).

```
<?php

$input = array(
 "ID" => 1,
 "settings" => array("key" => 1,"scrum" => array("last_key" =>1, "past_key" => 12) )
);

array_walk_recursive($input, function($v, $k, $needle_key) use (&$values){
    if($k == $needle_key) {
       $values[] = $v;
    }
},  'past_key');

var_dump($values);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(12)
  }
```

Comment: Of course the third param, could alternatively be inherited by the closure.