# I have a question about php search associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this ff. assoc array

```
$array = [
    'school' => [
        'college' => [
            'nursing' => ['n1a', 'n2a', 'n3a', 'n4a'],
            'hrm' => ['h1a', 'h2a', 'h3a', 'h4a'],
            'tourism' => ['t1a', 't2a', 't3a', 't4a'],
            'it' => ['i1a', 'i2a', 'i3a', 'i4a'],
        ],
        'senior' => [],
    ],
    'business' => [
        'office' => [
            'dep1' => ['team1', 'team2'],
            'dep2' => ['team1', 'team2'],
            'dep3' => ['team1', 'team2'],
            'dep4' => ['team1', 'team2'],
        ],
    ],
]
```

And I have this code, but this only search first level array.

```php
  function searchItemsByKey($array, $key) {
       $results = array();

          if (is_array($array))
          {

            if (isset($array[$key]) && key($array)==$key){
                $results[] = $array[$key];
            }

            foreach ($array as $sub_array){
                $results = array_merge($results, $this->searchItemsByKey($sub_array, $key));
            }
          }

         return  $results;
    }
```

All I want is to search all keys in this array that will result all arrays associated with keys like:

```php
searchItemsByKey($array, 'hrm');
```

That will return:

```php
['h1a', 'h2a', 'h3a', 'h4a']
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why is `key($array)==$key` in the if statement? if you remove it I think it will work. Can see here: https://3v4l.org/27jHf

Comment: Try a recursive function that will go deep in your array untill it find the key you want

Comment: oh that was quick, thanks mate @dWinder

Comment: will try that, thanks @MickaëlLeger

Comment: There's a nice answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3975706/661872 - shame not accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array_walk_recursive,

```
$result = [];
$search = "hrm";
function searchItemsByKey($array, $key)
{
    $retArr = [];
    if (is_array($array)) {
        if (!empty($array[$key])) {
            return $array[$key];
        }
        foreach ($array as $val) {
            $retArr = array_merge($retArr, searchItemsByKey($val, $key));
        }
    }
    return $retArr;
}
$temp = searchItemsByKey($array, 'hrm');
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/qIXij).

Comment: Notice this will take only the last recurrence of the key - the OP want all of them (as he does `result[] = ...` or `array_merge`)

Comment: Yes I am on correcting answer, I thought it wil give every key, but its sticking to leaf nodes.